# Why is my tries in my loop never decreasing in my program?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    int number1;
    Random number = new Random();
    Scanner numberCheck = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Try to guess the number 0-100\n");
    Integer answerOne = numberCheck.nextInt();
    for(int tries=10; tries > 0;tries-- ) {
        number1 = number.nextInt(101);
        
if (answerOne > number1){System.out.println("You are incorrect, answer is     
too high");}
            
else if (answerOne.equals(number1)){System.out.println("You are Correct !");}
                
else{System.out.println("You are incorrect, answer is too low");};
                    
if (answerOne.equals(number1)){System.out.println("Great Job");}
                        
else{System.out.println("(Tries left):"+tries+"\n");
        System.out.println("Try to guess the number 0-100\n");
        Integer answerTwo = numberCheck.nextInt();
        
if (answerTwo > number1){System.out.println("You are incorrect, answer is too high");}
        
else if (answerOne.equals(number1)){System.out.println("You are Correct !");}
            else{System.out.println("You are incorrect, answer is too low");};
                
if (answerOne.equals(number1)){System.out.println("Great Job");}
                    
else{System.out.println("(Tries left):"+tries+"\n");
        break;
}
}
    }
        }
            }
```

The tries is not working properly, I'm a novice coder and I know its probabaly something silly but I havent been able to figure out the issue here. I appricate any feedback.

Comment: Please [edit] your question (and your local code) to fix the indentation of your source code. It is difficult to read where which `if()` block starts and another one ends.

Comment: I'd also recommend following a more conventional bracing style, at least for Stack Overflow questions. (It's one thing to have your own personal or team preference - but when you're presenting code for the general public, using at least one of the regular conventions is usually helpful.)

Comment: You are break'ing from the loop after the first attempt. Also, why all this code for answerTwo, what is its purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You approach to the problem is pretty strange.
The propose is to guess a number (I think), but why you pick the number to guess in the loop ? why change every iteration ?

```
for (int tries = 10; tries > 0; tries--) {
    number1 = number.nextInt(101);
    ...
}
```

doesn't make sense to me. Second, why handle two answer per try ? Again, don't know, but the last block of code contains the error that break the code

```
if (answerOne.equals(number1)) { // this statement is always false, so you ever take the break
    System.out.println("Great Job");
} else {
    System.out.println("(Tries left):" + tries + "\n");
    break;
}
```

because,at that point `answerOne` is ever different from `number1`

To implement the ipotetical requirements corretly, you can simply do this:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner numberCheck = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Try to guess the number 0-100\n");
        int numberToGuess = new Random().nextInt(101); // pick at startup, just once
        for (int tries = 10; tries > 0; tries--) {
            int answer = numberCheck.nextInt(); // read user input
            if (answer > numberToGuess) { // check if answer is too high
                System.out.println("You are incorrect, answer is too high");
            } else if (answer < numberToGuess) { // check if answer is too low
                System.out.println("You are incorrect, answer is too low");
            } else { // check if answer is correct
                System.out.println("You are Correct !");
                tries = 0; // exit loop, avoid using break if not necessary
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Perfect ! but would you be able to tweak this a bit so it shows the tries left after every user input as I did in my original code ? that would help a ton thank you

Comment: simply add `System.out.println("(Tries left):"+tries+"\n");` after reading user input, cmon

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you should move the line Integer answerTwo = numberCheck.nextInt(); inside the loop and update the existing answerOne variable with the new guess from the user. Additionally, you should remove the unnecessary else block after the break statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mix up what needs to be inside the loop with what needs to be outside of it. You need initialization outside the loop and all your repetitive operations to be inside the loop. You do

```
Integer answerOne = numberCheck.nextInt();
```

outside your loop, whereas it's clear that you wanted your user to guess in each "try", so this needs to be put inside the loop. You want to do a single randomization, so your

```
number1 = number.nextInt(101);
```

should be done outside the loop, before the loop to be more precise.

And, inside the loop you will need the user to make a guess and, depending on his answer (too great, too low or correct), handle three separate cases. If the user guessed correctly, that's presumably a special case that you will need to handle, whereas in the other cases, just decrease the number of tries and have the user guess again.